# Draw points correctly with Canvas

Tags: java, python, android, opencv, canvas

I have a python script that draws landmarks on the contours of eye region with image input got from ckpts files  (model) using OpenCV. 
I want to draw those points ( landmarks ) in the same picture.
I got predictions points from the picture and I tried to draw those points (x,y) using Canvas but the results are different.
Difference between the two images:

[Landmarks are drawn using python script (OpenCV)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctkmB.png)

[Landmarks are draw using java code (Canvas)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN0Fx.png)

I have tried many ways and I use Canvas library to draw points on imageview ( I loaded the same image in assets folder ) but this doesn't solve my problem..

This is a python code that shows how to draw landmarks on image:

```py
predictions = estimator.predict(input_fn=_predict_input_fn)
        for _, result in enumerate(predictions):
            img = cv2.imread(result['name'].decode('ASCII') + '.jpg')
            print(result['logits'])
            print(result['name'])
            marks = np.reshape(result['logits'], (-1, 2)) * IMG_WIDTH
            print("reshape values  "+str(np.reshape(result['logits'], (-1,2))))
            print("marks  "+str(marks))

            for mark in marks:
                cv2.circle(img, (int(mark[0]), int(
                    mark[1])), 1, (0, 255, 0), -1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            try:
                img = cv2.resize(img, (512, 512))
                cv2.imshow('result', img)
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))
           # output_node_names = [n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
           # print(output_node_names)
            cv2.waitKey()
```

This file shows print logs from python code:

```
[0.33135968 0.19592011 0.34212315 0.17297666 0.36624995 0.16413747
 0.3894139  0.17440952 0.39828074 0.1978043  0.3891497  0.22268474
 0.36345637 0.22974193 0.3401759  0.2193309  0.30167252 0.20411113
 0.3167112  0.19134495 0.33793524 0.18388326 0.3642417  0.18049955
 0.3903508  0.18533507 0.40906873 0.1957745  0.42142123 0.21091096
 0.40550107 0.21829814 0.38345626 0.22071144 0.35900232 0.22142673
 0.3363348  0.21877256 0.3161971  0.2133534  0.62843406 0.21482795
 0.6389724  0.1914106  0.6628249  0.1835615  0.6858679  0.19583184
 0.6946868  0.22111627 0.6840309  0.24444285 0.66027373 0.25241333
 0.6351568  0.24192403 0.60499936 0.22642238 0.6210091  0.21289764
 0.6423563  0.2042976  0.6685919  0.20277795 0.69201195 0.20948553
 0.70882106 0.22015369 0.71931773 0.23518339 0.7076659  0.24166131
 0.69054717 0.24350837 0.6694564  0.24258481 0.64537776 0.23927754
 0.62199306 0.23511863]
b'C:\\Users\\*******\\cnn-facial-landmark\\targetiris\\irisdata-300VW_Dataset_2015_12_14-017-000880'
reshape values  [[0.33135968 0.19592011]
 [0.34212315 0.17297666]
 [0.36624995 0.16413747]
 [0.3894139  0.17440952]
 [0.39828074 0.1978043 ]
 [0.3891497  0.22268474]
 [0.36345637 0.22974193]
 [0.3401759  0.2193309 ]
 [0.30167252 0.20411113]
 [0.3167112  0.19134495]
 [0.33793524 0.18388326]
 [0.3642417  0.18049955]
 [0.3903508  0.18533507]
 [0.40906873 0.1957745 ]
 [0.42142123 0.21091096]
 [0.40550107 0.21829814]
 [0.38345626 0.22071144]
 [0.35900232 0.22142673]
 [0.3363348  0.21877256]
 [0.3161971  0.2133534 ]
 [0.62843406 0.21482795]
 [0.6389724  0.1914106 ]
 [0.6628249  0.1835615 ]
 [0.6858679  0.19583184]
 [0.6946868  0.22111627]
 [0.6840309  0.24444285]
 [0.66027373 0.25241333]
 [0.6351568  0.24192403]
 [0.60499936 0.22642238]
 [0.6210091  0.21289764]
 [0.6423563  0.2042976 ]
 [0.6685919  0.20277795]
 [0.69201195 0.20948553]
 [0.70882106 0.22015369]
 [0.71931773 0.23518339]
 [0.7076659  0.24166131]
 [0.69054717 0.24350837]
 [0.6694564  0.24258481]
 [0.64537776 0.23927754]
 [0.62199306 0.23511863]]
marks  [[37.112286 21.943052]
 [38.317795 19.373386]
 [41.019993 18.383396]
 [43.614357 19.533867]
 [44.607445 22.154081]
 [43.584766 24.940691]
 [40.707115 25.731096]
 [38.0997   24.565062]
 [33.787323 22.860447]
 [35.471653 21.430634]
 [37.848747 20.594925]
 [40.79507  20.21595 ]
 [43.719288 20.757528]
 [45.815697 21.926743]
 [47.199177 23.622028]
 [45.41612  24.44939 ]
 [42.9471   24.71968 ]
 [40.20826  24.799793]
 [37.6695   24.502527]
 [35.414074 23.89558 ]
 [70.38461  24.06073 ]
 [71.56491  21.437988]
 [74.23639  20.558887]
 [76.81721  21.933167]
 [77.80492  24.765022]
 [76.61146  27.3776  ]
 [73.95066  28.270294]
 [71.137566 27.095491]
 [67.759926 25.359306]
 [69.553024 23.844536]
 [71.9439   22.881332]
 [74.88229  22.71113 ]
 [77.50534  23.46238 ]
 [79.387955 24.657213]
 [80.56358  26.34054 ]
 [79.25858  27.066067]
 [77.341286 27.272938]
 [74.97912  27.169498]
 [72.28231  26.799084]
 [69.66322  26.333286]]
```

Java code (Android)

```java
  private void drawpoint(ImageView imageView,float x,float y, int raduis){
        myOptions.inDither = true;
        myOptions.inScaled = false;
        myOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;// important
        myOptions.inPurgeable = true;
        canvas.drawCircle(x,y, raduis, paint);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);
    }
         drawpoint(image2,  38,  19,1);
            drawpoint(image2,41,18,1);
            drawpoint(image2,43,19,1);
            drawpoint(image2,40,25,1);
            drawpoint(image2,38,24,1);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I used the OpenCV library for drawing in Android instead of Canvas library.
I have used exactly this function:
`Imgproc.circle()`